# "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding" while decrypting data from table storage

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-table-storage

Reaching out to for your help / support. 
We have a requirement to Encrypt the data in table storage and Decrypt the data while pulling it from table storage. Tried with the sample application found in https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net.
In the sample application Encryption and Decyption is happening in same method. In my case it rasing error in "Decrypt" function and the error is **- "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding"** But we need to two separate functions. Even we need to pull the data through Table Query.
Please find below is my code -

const string DemoTable = "demotable";

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        RsaKey key = new RsaKey("mydemokey");
        string partitionid = "mydemoid123456";

        EncryptData(partitionid, key);

        DecryptData(partitionid, key);
    }

    public static void EncryptData(string partitionid,  RsaKey rsakey)
    {           
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = EncryptionShared.Utility.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString();
        CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(DemoTable);

        try
        {
            table.Create();

            EncryptedEntity ent = new EncryptedEntity() { PartitionKey = partitionid, RowKey = "DemoKey1" };
            ent.Populate();

            TableRequestOptions insertOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
            {
                EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(rsakey, null)
            };                                
            table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(ent), insertOptions, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void DecryptData(string partitionid, RsaKey rsakey)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = EncryptionShared.Utility.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString();
        CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(DemoTable);

        try
        {
            EncryptedEntity ent = new EncryptedEntity() { PartitionKey = partitionid, RowKey = "DemoKey1" };
            ent.Populate();
            LocalResolver resolver = new LocalResolver();
            resolver.Add(rsakey);
            TableRequestOptions retrieveOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
            {
                EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(null, resolver)
            };
            TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve(ent.PartitionKey, ent.RowKey);
            TableResult result = table.Execute(operation, retrieveOptions, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Am I doing any mistake or any other option available to Encypt and Decrypt the data in Table Storage (including partitionkey).

[Decrypt Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxnlL.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards,
Debasis

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I found  you add the rsakey to the LocalResolver object in the DecryptData method.

As far as I know, the raskey is a one-time-use symmetric key and its value is not same after generated.

If you don’t use the right raskey(generated when you update the table entity), you couldn’t get the right result from the table storage.

More details about how the client-side encryption worked you could refer to follow step and link:

Encryption via the envelope technique works in the following way:

1. The Azure storage client library generates a content encryption key (CEK), which is a one-time-use symmetric key.
2. User data is encrypted using this CEK.
3. The CEK is then wrapped (encrypted) using the key encryption key (KEK). The KEK is identified by a key identifier and can be an asymmetric key pair or a symmetric key and can be managed locally or stored in Azure Key Vaults.
   The storage client library itself never has access to KEK. The library invokes the key wrapping algorithm that is provided by Key Vault. Users can choose to use custom providers for key wrapping/unwrapping if desired.
4. The encrypted data is then uploaded to the Azure Storage service. The wrapped key along with some additional encryption metadata is either stored as metadata (on a blob) or interpolated with the encrypted data (queue messages and table entities).

Decryption via the envelope technique works in the following way:

1. The client library assumes that the user is managing the key encryption key (KEK) either locally or in Azure Key Vaults. The user does not need to know the specific key that was used for encryption. Instead, a key resolver which resolves different key identifiers to keys can be set up and used.
2. The client library downloads the encrypted data along with any encryption material that is stored on the service.
3. The wrapped content encryption key (CEK) is then unwrapped (decrypted) using the key encryption key (KEK). Here again, the client library does not have access to KEK. It simply invokes the custom or Key Vault provider’s unwrapping algorithm.
4. The content encryption key (CEK) is then used to decrypt the encrypted user data.

Link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-client-side-encryption

I suggest you could use below codes to get the right result.

```
class Program
{
    const string DemoTable = "demotable";
    const string ConnectionString = "yourconnectionstring";

    // For retrieves, a resolver can be set up that will help pick the key based on the key id.
    static LocalResolver resolver = new LocalResolver();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RsaKey key = new RsaKey("mydemokey");
        string partitionid = "mydemoid123456";
        EncryptData(partitionid, key);
        DecryptData(partitionid, key);
    }

    public static void EncryptData(string partitionid, RsaKey rsakey)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

        CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(DemoTable);

        try
        {
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
            EncryptedEntity ent = new EncryptedEntity() { PartitionKey = partitionid, RowKey = "DemoKey1" ,Test = "aaaa" };
            //ent.Populate();
            TableRequestOptions insertOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
            {
                EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(rsakey, null)
            };
            resolver.Add(rsakey);
            table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(ent), insertOptions, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void DecryptData(string partitionid, RsaKey rsakey)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(DemoTable);

        try
        {
            EncryptedEntity ent = new EncryptedEntity() { PartitionKey = partitionid, RowKey = "DemoKey1" };
            //ent.Populate();

            TableRequestOptions retrieveOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
            {
                EncryptionPolicy = new TableEncryptionPolicy(null, resolver)
            };
            TableOperation operation = TableOperation.Retrieve(ent.PartitionKey, ent.RowKey);
            TableResult result = table.Execute(operation, retrieveOptions, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Result:
[image]

Besides, the example above stored the key value in the local, normally we will use the Azure Key Vault service to store key.

More details, you could refer to follow link:

[What is Azure Key Vault?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)

[Encrypt and decrypt in Microsoft Azure Storage using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#encrypt-blob-and-upload)

Comment: Apologize I dii the mistake. Created a static class for resolver and Rsakey, now I am able to encrypt and decrypt table storage data. I have two different function one is "Encrypt" and another is "Decrypt" and both are present in different class. We will encrypt the data and other party will decrypt the data to generate the report. Now facing issue while encrypting "GUID" , "Int" datatype. it shows {"Unsupported type : Guid encountered during encryption. Only string properties can be encrypted on the client side."}. Do I need to change the property to "string" for all entities.

Comment: Yes, as this artic (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-client-side-encryption), "Note that only string properties can be encrypted. If other types of properties are to be encrypted, they must be converted to strings. The encrypted strings are stored on the service as binary properties, and they are converted back to strings after decryption.",  so you need to change the property to "string" for all entities